# Laplacian of an integral

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to show that $u(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{tdt}{|x-te_1|}$ is harmonic on $\mathbb R^3\setminus\{te_1:t\in[0,1]\}$ where $e_1=(1,0,0)^T$.

So far I've computed the integral:

$u(x)=\operatorname{sign}(x_1)(x_1\log|x_1|-x_1\log|1-x_1|-1)$

However I don't seem to get the Laplacian right since

$u_{xx}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{(x_1-1)^2x_1}\neq0 $
(for $x_1-t>0$).
Therefore the function would not be harmonic.
Are my computations wrong? Is there an easier way to show the function is harmonic?

Comment: Il $x$ is an $\mathbb{R}^3$ vector, what does it means $(x^2-1)x$? How can the integral be independent on $x_2, x_3$?

Comment: That's true. I meant $x_1$, of course. And apparently I completely ignored $x_2, x_3$. I'll try again, thanks!